# Is there a way to find out if a .js file is using jquery sintax?

Tags: jquery, scanning

I have several .js files (kinda long files), and I would like to know if there is a way to scan those files and find out if there is any jquery syntax present.

Regards,

Comment: Remove the jquery import, load in browser, look at error console.

Comment: 1) Search the file for uses of `jQuery` or `$` in an editor (with the "whole word" or similar option enabled). 2) Try a linter like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) or [ESLint](http://eslint.org/). Look for any warning of `jQuery` or `$` not being defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal/command line:

```
for file in *.js;
  do
    grep "\$(\|jQuery(" $file;
  done;
```

This will search all JS files in the present directory and return any actual occurrence of jQuery's telltale `"$("` OR non-aliased instance of `jQuery(`.
You can use a regex for more specific selectors if you want.

This will return the filename instead of the code (make sure there are no spaces in the filename).

```
for file in *.js
  do
    if grep -q "\$(\|jQuery(" $file;
    then echo "$file likely uses jQuery";
    fi
  done
```

Single line:

```
for file in *.js; do if grep -q "\$(\|jQuery(" $file; then echo "$file likely uses jQuery"; fi; done;
```

Note that this doesn't account for any other libraries or languages that may use `$`and could have false positives if your JS includes something like "Bob loves money $(money!)," which clearly isn't jQuery at all. But, at least it will still flag all the files for you to check...

Comment: I would rather do `grep -q "(\$\(|jQuery)"` since (rarely) jQuery is assigned to q() or something else.

Comment: Was about to mention `jQuery` vs `$` :) Will add